# How to filter product.custom_fields by multiple values in name filed in Big Commerce

Tags: handlebars.js, bigcommerce

I am trying to return all `product.custom_fields` unless the name field contains 'Feature, Width, Height or Depth'.

I can get the logic to work by using the following two code variations if filtering by one value:

```
{{#each product.custom_fields}}
            {{#unless (occurrences name 'Height')}}
            {{else}}
              <tr>
                <th>{{ name }}</th>
                <td>{{ sanitize value }}</td>
              </tr>
            {{/unless}}
          {{/each}}
```

and

```
{{#each product.custom_fields}}
              {{#startsWith 'Feature' name}}
              {{else}}
                {{#if value '!==' 'true'}}
                  <tr>
                    <th>{{ name }}</th>
                    <td>{{ sanitize value }}</td>
                  </tr>
                {{/if}}
              {{/startsWith}}
            {{/each}}
```

But when trying to the same for multiple it breaks. e.g.

```
{{#unless (occurrences name 'Height' occurrences name 'Width' occurrences name 'Depth' occurrences name 'Feature')}}
```

Handlebars is something i've only just started using so any advice / best practices for trying to do more complex filtering would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless, StartsWith, If, Contains all just look at a single item. To group multiple items, you will actually need to use a different helper: and, or, all , any.

One example of this:

```
{{#each product.custom_fields}}
{{#any (occurrences name 'Height') (occurrences name 'Width') (occurrences name 'Depth') (occurrences name 'Feature')}}
{{else}}
    <tr>
    <th>{{ name }}</th>
    <td>{{ sanitize value }}</td>
    </tr>
{{/any}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: this did exactly what I needed! Thank you